# Queria saber como fazer para o botão mudar de cor

Tags: javascript, html

**Esse é o código funcionando sem trocar de cor:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>

<body>
  <form>
    <button  type="button" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus" value="botao ligado" onclick="mostrar(this)">
      <p>botao ligado</p>
    </button>
  </form>

  <script>
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

    button.addEventListener('click', updateButton);

    function updateButton() {
      if (button.value === 'botao desligado') {
        button.value = 'botao ligado';
        paragraph.textContent = 'botao ligado';
      } else {
        button.value = 'botao desligado';
        paragraph.textContent = 'botao desligado';
      }
    }

    function mostrar(e) {
      if (e.classList.contains("glyphicon-plus")) {
        e.classList.remove("glyphicon-plus");
        e.classList.add("glyphicon-minus");
        $cor = "btn-success";
      } else {
        e.classList.remove("glyphicon-minus");
        e.classList.add("glyphicon-plus");
      }

    }
  </script>

</body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

</html>
```

**Eu tentei colocar uma variável com a cor do botão mas ele não muda. Assim:**

```
<button name="referencia" type="button" class="btn <?php echo ($cor);?> glyphicon glyphicon-plus" value="botao ligado" onclick="mostrar(this)">
<p>botao ligado</p>
</button>

<script>
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

button.addEventListener('click', updateButton);

function updateButton() {
  if (button.value === 'botao desligado') {
    button.value = 'botao ligado';
    paragraph.textContent = 'botao ligado';
    $cor="btn-success";
  } else {
    button.value = 'botao desligado';
    paragraph.textContent = 'botao desligado';
    $cor="btn-danger"; 
  }
}

function mostrar(e) {
  if (e.classList.contains("glyphicon-plus")) { 
    e.classList.remove("glyphicon-plus"); 
    e.classList.add("glyphicon-minus"); 
  } else {
    e.classList.remove("glyphicon-minus"); 
    e.classList.add("glyphicon-plus"); 
  }
 }
</script>
```

O meu colega consegue fazer isso com input no lugar do button

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="button" style="color:white" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')" ; />

  <script>
    var count = 1;

    function setColor(btn, color) {
      var property = document.getElementById(btn);
      if (count == 0) {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "green"
        count = 1;
      } else {
        property.style.backgroundColor = "red"
        count = 0;
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você não deve misturar linguagens assim. Use apenas o JavaScript. Ao invés de tentar alimentar essa variável você deve apenas adicionar a classe ao botão `button.classList.add("btn-success")`.

Não use `<p>` dentro de `<button>` é desnecessário.

```
<button type="button" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
    botao desligado
</button>

<script>
const button = document.querySelector('button');
let buttonOn = false

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!buttonOn) {
    buttonOn = true;
    button.innerHTML = 'botao ligado';
    button.classList.add("btn-success");
  } else {
    buttonOn = false;
    button.innerHTML = 'botao desligado';
    button.classList.add("btn-danger"); 
  }
})

</script>
```

Apenas uma variável simples dizendo se o botão está ligado ou não.

Comment: Vlw amigo, ficou show mas ñ deu muito certo. Um colega consegui fazer com input vou tentar fazer com button. O código do meu colega:

Comment: <input type="button" id="button" value="button" style="color:white" onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')" ; />
  
  <script>
    var count = 1;
    function setColor(btn, color) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "green"
            count = 1;        
        }
        else {
            property.style.backgroundColor = "red"
            count = 0;
        }
    }
  </script>

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha compreendido você então. @moigamijunior caso precise de ajuda.

Answer (score -2):

Você poderia também, apenas definir um estilo para seu botão com JS mesmo, dentro do seu `IF` existente, com `elemento.style.backgroundColor = "COR_DE_SUA_ESCOLHA";`.

Por exemplo:

```
function updateButton() {
  if (button.value === 'botao desligado') {
        button.value = 'botao ligado';
        paragraph.textContent = 'botao ligado';

        button.style.backgroundColor = "Green";

      } else {
        button.value = 'botao desligado';
        paragraph.textContent = 'botao desligado';
        
        button.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
    
      }
}
```

Acredito que assim seria mais simples. Espero que ajude.